# .NET POP3 Library that supports Proxy

Tags: c#, pop3

I am looking for a pop3 library that will let me use a proxy. I have tried OpenPop.NET but it doesn't support proxy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTTP Proxies. Is it possible?

Comment: @SLaks You can use HTTP proxy to tunnel any protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [Mail.dll POP3 component](http://www.limilabs.com/mail). Please note that it's a commercial product that I've created.

It supports HTTP and SOCKS proxies:

http://www.limilabs.com/blog/imap-pop3-smtp-via-http-socks-proxy

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the developers of OpenPop.NET.
I have thought about supporting proxies, but have not added it as of yet. However, the Pop3Client  [Connect method](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/index.html) takes a stream, which it uses to communicate with the server. If you supply a stream, which is a proxied stream, then OpenPop.NET would work fine with it.
I have found [a starksoft proxy project](http://code.google.com/p/starksoft-component-libraries/) that should be able to deliver such streams. I have not tested it though. Also see [this](http://starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html) for more information on the starksoft proxy.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there aren't many proxy types able to connect a POP server other than SOCKS.

A quick search on google lead me to [this](http://www.starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html). It allows you to establish a TcpClient connection through a proxy.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx) is the best POP3 client I have ever seen (and used many times), especially if you need to work with the content of retrieved mails. It uses the TcpClient class to establish connections with the POP server and the code is full of comments.
You'll just have to modify the sources (mainly Pop3MailClient) here and there to improve the client so it can use a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug:

aspNetPOP3 supports Socks proxy servers.

http://www.aspNetPOP3.com

--Dave